# Async-Await thread behavior and questions

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

What is the use of an async await method that only call one liners async await methods? How many threads do they span? How much CPU you can end up consuming?
Hi, lately I'm seeing a lot of methods using the async and await keywords. I still cannot wrap my head around the use of them and the underlying behavior as well as their advantage when applied like below. I ahve also obseved a problem with the CPU (going 100%) when they use it for everything and I'm seeing thread.run as the culprit for cpu utilization for some of this cases.

myController.cs

```
[HttpPost]

[ProducesResponseType(body)]

public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Body body){

_MyClassService.sendMessage(body);

return Ok(body);

}
```

My Service class

```
Myclass.cs

private async void sendMessage(){

await SendToProperChannel();

}



private async Task SendToProperChannel(){

await DoWorkInProperChannel();

}



private Task<int> DoWorkInProperChannel(){

await SomethingThatTakes5Seconds();

return 1+1;

}
```

**According to my little knowledge.**

We are making the controller request async in order to not block main threads, allowing to receive higher throughput at the controller level.

We are making also all the functions async to not block the upper threads that call those methods.

I also understand that since we have so many awaits, everyone returns a task but also a thread is handling that work waiting for the completion of this.

I'm still not clear on the thread number but I believe we are spawning more than 1 thread to fulfill a single request.

**My questions.**

What is the use of having one liners await if the upper method cannot continue without the response? The API can, in fact, receive more throughput, but down from there everything will be kind of sync, also spawning more threads just for jumping between methods in my class doesn't seem healthy.

If I only awaiting on one liners, in this specific code, the result would not be the same as removing the awaits?

All methods will also handle more throughput, since they don't block, but will also spawn more threads?

How is the syntax for starting an async method and waiting for the response way down inside the same method.

*Example:*

```
private async Task<int> myAsyncWorkerMethod(){

var myNeededValue=methodThatINeed();

var mySecondValue=methodWithSecondValue();

await myNeededValue;

await mySecondValue;

return myNeededValue+mySecondValue;

}
```

What is the benefit from async and await against having just a thread pool that handles all downstream calls, which you can easily control its size and can easily detect thread starvation and queue depth? (I might be using some java terms in here that might not apply)

**Thoughts**

In other lenguages I have seen the repercussions of thread context change, if your CPU is not powerful enough or you have thread starvation because of the thread pool size, does this .net uncontrolled thread pool would not have the same repercussions and just use the CPU as much as he wants?

You don't need to create an async invocation if you need them to return the response for the await statement. making asynchronous is only needed when you need to do some work on the above method?

Even if you are awaiting method results from another class unless you don't want to block the main thread you should also not wait for it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: there is no `Thread.sleep` but `Thread.Sleep` which return void ... so it cannot be used like `await Thread.Sleep(..)`

Comment: Yeah, you should be awaiting `Task.Delay`, not `Thread.Sleep`.  `Thread.Sleep` does what it says - it puts the thread to sleep for N milliseconds, wasting that thread for that time (which is the opposite of what `await` is good for

Comment: after edit ... the problem is in `SomethingThatTakes5Seconds`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer your points and questions all at once:

> "We are making the controller request async in order to not block main threads, allowing to receive higher throughput at the controller level."

No, that's completely incorrect. Turn on proper compiler exceptions and you will see that using `async` without `await` is a waste of time that gives you no value and generates useless IL code.

> "I also understand that since we have so many awaits, everyone returns a task but also a thread is handling that work waiting for the completion of this."

[There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

> "I'm still not clear on the thread number but I believe we are spawning more than 1 thread to fulfill a single request."

As mentioned above, that is invalid as well.

> What is the use of having one liners await if the upper method cannot continue without the response?

Basically none, the code could have been just:

```
private async void sendMessage()
{    
    await DoWorkInProperChannel();
}

private Task<int> DoWorkInProperChannel()
{
    // `await Thread.Sleep()` is not valid, `Sleep` returns `void` 
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    return 1+1;
}
```

Note: not a single new thread is created from the code above; not in the original version or in mine.

> If I only awaiting on one liners, in this specific code, the result would not be the same as removing the awaits?

Not at all, you would need to `return` the `Task` generated for the code to be the same. Except, of course, in the case of the `async void` method, where you cannot return anything.

> ```
> private async Task<int> myAsyncWorkerMethod()
> {
>     var myNeededValue=methodThatINeed();
>     var mySecondValue=methodWithSecondValue();
>     await myNeededValue;
>     await mySecondValue;
>
>     return myNeededValue+mySecondValue;
> }
> ```

This is known as parallel asynchronous code and it has nothing to do with the previous example. Whether you can use parallel code or not depends on what you are doing.

> In other languages I have seen the repercussions of thread context change, if your CPU is not powerful enough or you have thread starvation because of the thread pool size, does this .net uncontrolled thread pool would not have the same repercussions and just use the CPU as much as he wants?

There is not a single context change in the code you posted, so this is not relevant.

> Even if you are awaiting method results from another class unless you don't want to block the main thread you should also not wait for it.

You are using ASP.NET Core, there's no main thread.

Comment: On the first point, I expressed myself incorrectly,  I was referring to making it async and put and await inside the function so then it will not block the asp.net thread that I tought it was the end goal of the async/await at the controller level.

On the same theme, So there is no CPU impact on having a high amount of awaits over and over in the same stack? So If I have 10 awaits, it will only use one thread and CPU impact will be the same as removing the async/await statements?

Comment: @MBG There is some cost to having a long chain of aync methods, but only because of the cost of allocating a new state-machine for every method (so mostly pressure on the GC). If your async method is a one-liner, don't use await: remove the `async` keyword and directly return the task. If you do so, then the only cost caused by your method will be a method call, which will probably be inlined by the JIT compiler (therefore: no cost at all)

Comment: @KevinGosse Weird things can happen if you elide `async` and `await` to run a `Task`, see [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html). In that case, it's best to just avoid creating the method

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto As long as it's a one-liner (so no 'using' block, try/catch, or whatever), nothing weird will happen

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Why writing a code in a way that degrades performance for no added readability?

Comment: @KevinGosse I meant the method that only returns the other method could be avoided. I now realize the last comment didn't make sense

Comment: @KevinGosse so in cases like this, is better to do the async/await only on the method that calls the awaitable function, and then return a task instead of an awaitable upstream? Do you have an example of this?

Comment: @MBG The `SendToProperChannel` method for instance can be rewritten `private Task SendToProperChannel() { return DoWorkInProperChannel(); }` (no async/await). But as @CamiloTerevinto rightfully mentioned, it's even better if you can remove the method altogether